# Azure bot Languages

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, voice, azure-bot-service

I have a hard time understanding how I create a bot in a language other than English.  Following the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language?tabs=v2x), I'm just supposed to select the language in creating a new BOT, but I do not have such an option.

I'm probably missing something.

The final goal - to create a Hebrew-speaking IVR for dynamics 365 omnichannel voice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Select the language you want to use` in step 2 is referring to *programming language*. You're being asked to choose between C# and Node in the selector above the list of templates.

The instructions for how to create a multilingual bot are further down in that document. You just haven't gotten far enough in the document yet. After following the steps for building a basic bot, the document then shows you how to [update language settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language?tabs=v2x#update-language-settings), and from there you can follow the rest of the document to add support for your language.

The Composer application itself will only display in English, but you can author bot responses in other languages.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error of not supporting a particular language even though it appears in the list of languages, I may need to install something / add something. https://www.screencast.com/t/yEmJFDVH2

Comment: Hebrew is supported by Composer, but not by LUIS, the Cognitive Language Understanding service. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support) is the list of LUIS-supported languages.

You will be able to author bot responses in Hebrew, but you will not be able to use LUIS as a language recognizer.